# Not able to scroll till end in android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-webview

I have  TextView+webview as ListItem of ListView. When I change orientation. I am reloading all files as well setting adapter again and I am calling following code to select item from list programtically so I can get onItemClick call same ways as user would have clicked.

```
if(position!=-1 && getAdapter()!=null){
                requestFocusFromTouch();
                performItemClick(
                        getAdapter().getView(position,
                                null, null), position,
                        getAdapter().getItemId(position));
            }
```

Now when I change orientation of screen, the selected item's webview is not scrolling till the end. It seems that it is not changing its scrolled position when we change orientation (Even though we reset adapter).

I tried `requestlayout()`, `forcelayout()`, `invalidate()`,`reload()` method of webview but none of them seems to be working.

Comment: I used delay while selecting item by code using call performItemClick method but it is not best solution i think their should be better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have your WebViews heights set to wrap_contents. This means that their heights are 0 when the list is loaded and they expand to a > 0 height at some point. One way to solve your issue would be to wait for all of the webviews to call onSizeChanged before scrolling, another option would be to re-position the list every time the lists contents change size.

Comment: HI, Thanks for your response. Actually webview are only visible when user click on list item. And i need to set height everytime user click on list item (TextView).